# How can I overwrite only the values in a range after applying a formula to it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have formulas going down some columns, but I want to overwrite the same cells with only the values. I've tried a couple things but haven't been able to get it to work, it still leaves the formula in the cells. This is an example of what I have for one of the columns.

```
  function Info() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("J2").setFormula("=SHIP(G2)");

  var lr1 = ss.getLastRow();
  var fillDownRange1 = ss.getRange(2, 10, lr1-1, 1);
  ss.getRange("J2").copyTo(fillDownRange1);
  ss.getRange("J:J").activate();
  ss.getActiveRangeList().setFontWeight("bold");
  ss.getRange("J2:J"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType, {contentsOnly:true};
```

Comment: Please show the structure of your sheet including the formulas that it contains. Please checkout [mcve].

Comment: What do you expect  this to do? `ss.getRange("J2:J"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType, {contentsOnly:true};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Info() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange("J2").setFormula("=SHIP(G2)");
  let rg1 = sh.getRange(2, 10, sh.getLastRow()  - 1, 1);
  let vs = rg1.getDisplayValues();
  rg1.setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! can you explain it, and what was wrong with mine?

Comment: The main points are: [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) and [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues), two dimensional arrays

Comment: I never debug other peoples code if I can avoid it.  The code is very simple just go through it line by line while reading the documentation while you do.